# viewing MS Visual Studio 2010 localhost through windows virtual machine

Tags: visual-studio-2010, localhost

I currently test .net aplications using visual studio 2010. I need to test the site in ie6 so need to run through windows virtual machine. Is there any way to do this?

Regards,

Phil

Comment: the problem is that you can't connect to Web Development server from virtual machine?

Comment: to view locally, I press F5. which brings up http://localhost:portnumber/ yet I cannot view this through virtual machine. How do i?

Answer (score 0):

When connecting from virtual machine, you need to replace localhost with host machine name.
And, of course, there should be network connection between host machine and virtual one.

Second, you can't connect to Web Development Server from another machine (virtual or real) since it doesn't support remote connections. You need to deploy your application on IIS

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.markbetz.net/2010/09/15/remote-connections-to-visual-studios-web-server/) might be a possible solution: use port forwarding to connect your virtual machine to the VS webserver.